# Facebook - Determine if user is a fan externally

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, html

Is it possible to determine whether a user is a fan of Facebook?  I know it was possible but I'm struggling with it - has the FB api changed recently?  I followed an answer in another post which led me to this jfiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/X4bn6/1042/

although it looks exactly like what i'm after- and works fine in jsfiddle - when i recreate outside jsfiddle - the script simply doesn't run - for example -

http://jsfiddle.net/X4bn6/1042/show/

this script is triggered - but doesnt return anything -

```
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    alert(response)
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    hideLogin();
    checkLike(response.authResponse.userID)
  } else {
    showLogin();
  }
 });
 alert('mmm')
```

Very frustrating, wondered if it was a security issue - i have ran on a server - cant find any reasons online - Anyone have any ideas at all?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify permission to access a user's likes.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Permission is called: user_likes

Answer (score 0):

More than likely it's because you are running FB.init() on document load, which is ready well before the external FB js SDK (all.js) is added to your page.

When the facebook js sdk is loaded (it's being appended to your document by that self invoking (executing) anonymous function), it fires `fbAsyncInit()`.

Define a fbAsyncInit() function in your global scope, and put your FB.init() and any other FB subscription or whathaveyou in there.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/